# Bundle with custom Attribute don't appear in frontend - magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes, bundle, catalog

Hi i'm working with magento and i must create a custom Bundle Product with a custom Attribute Set.

This Bundle have "pipe" Attribute Set and the products in the selection are "pipe" Attribute Set. I've try with "default" Attribute Set for selection products too.

the problem is that it don't show up un the frontend.

If i make the same Bundle product with the "default" Attribute Set it show up.

How i can solve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already create Attribute
1. go to Manage Attribute Sets choose "default" You will see Unassigned Attributes at the right hand. 
drag it to your correct position.

or

2.go to Manage Attributes that you create.

Allow HTML Tags on Frontend = yes

Visible on Product View Page on Front-end = yes <<<< (this one will show your attributes at the front end)

Used in Product Listing = yes

Used for Sorting in Product Listing = yes